Spool each page separately in Windows 11
Is there any way in Windows 11 to have the printer (HP color laserjet cm2320fxi in this case) spool each copy of a print sequentially vs 1 large print job?  I'm printing 25 copies of a single page file, and my printer jams whenever it tries to print 2 pages in a row (its an issue with an old servo sticking a bit)
I can manually go into Word and hit print 25 times, but I'd rather find a way to spool each one individually so that it has a short gap between prints to prevent the jamming

Feed the paper sheet by sheet?

Sure, but that's even more time/effort vs individually submitting print jobs from my computer.  I'd need to sit there, wait for it to print, then it complains about being out of paper; then open it up and add a new sheet
